# why does virtualenv workon not take me to the env directory

Tags: ubuntu, virtualenv, ubuntu-server, virtualenvwrapper

I have virtualenv setup and it is working well accept for one annoying issue. when I use the workon  command to enter an environment the environment is logs in correctly but I do not get automatically directed to the environments root directory.

I have added the following lines to my `.bashrc` file:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

and reloaded it (source `.bashrc`), but when I enter an environment I am still left in my ubuntu user home directory. I have also tries restarting my server, but still no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think `workon` changes to the environment directory. The solution would is to put that  in `postactivate` file of your virtualenv.

E.g. I have following in my `<virtual_env_dir>/bin/postactivate`

```
cd /home/myuser/work/
```

Comment: See @Casebash 's solution using ```setvirtualenvproject```.

Answer (score 4):

Environments are separate from projects with virtualenvwrapper. You first need to ensure that the `$PROJECT_HOME` variable is set. Then you can use the `mkproject` command to create an environment and a project in `$PROJECT_HOME'. Alternatively, you can use [setvirtualenvproject](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#setvirtualenvproject) to associate an existing project with an existing virtual environment.

Comment: With this solution, to switch into the virtualenv, you'd need to `workon <virtualenv> && cdproject`.

Comment: Not if you use ```setvirtualenvproject <env_dir> <project_dir>``` That worked perfectly for me.